# Storing a (long long) in a CoreData model

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

Very beginner-level question here that I can't seem to solve:

In Objective-C, I can get millis since 1970 with `(long long)([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000.0)` (from [here](https://currentmillis.com/)).

I'd like to store in a CoreData model, but the only options that I have are:

[image]

The thing is, I don't even know what I'm converting *from*, as the signature for timeIntervalSince1970 is: `(instancetype)dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:(NSTimeInterval)secs;`

From a quick Google, I find that `(instancetype)` is the instance that I'm operating on (if I understand right), which is `NSDate`. If this represents the number of seconds since 1970, it makes sense to multiply by 1000 to get milliseconds. Why can I multiply NSDate by (int) though? Nothing in the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdate?language=objc) leads me to believe that this is the proper way to do things.

And this is where I get a little stuck. I multiply by 1000 and end up with *something* that I then cast to (long long), which I'm cool with, but then need to choose a suitable type from CoreData's list of possibilities that has the precision of storing a (long long) or something equivalent.

- What datatype should I choose within CoreData?
- What does multiplying an NSDate by an integer return me? (Possibly with a reference more useful than Apple's docs?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `long long` is the same as an Integer 64.

You cannot multiply an `NSDate` by an integer at all. An `NSDate` is an instant in time. It is possible to ask it how many seconds that instant is from several reference dates (one of which is the unix epoch), but `NSDate` itself is not that thing. It's the instant in time. (Internally it's stored as a `Double` number of seconds since the "reference date" 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 2001, but this is an implementation detail and you shouldn't worry about it.)

As a rule, though, you should store dates as dates in Core Data. Don't convert to numbers or think in milliseconds. This is a bug pit. If you have a date, select the "Date" type in Core Data to store it.

[`-dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970` returns an `NSTimeInterval`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdate/1407504-timeintervalsince1970?language=objc), which is a typealias for `Double`. I'm not sure where you're seeing `(instancetype)` as the return value. As you say, that would be `NSDate`, which wouldn't make sense.

Comment: Ah, I was misinterpreting the docs. `NSTimeInterval` makes a lot more sense, thanks for that. The only reason that I have to think about it as milliseconds since 1970 is because I'm sending it to a server, which is running a different language, and I have to be sure the two values are representing the same thing on each side.

Comment: That's fine, but convert to milliseconds at the last moment (when you're getting ready to send to the server) and convert any milliseconds the server sends you to a Date immediately when it comes in. Working in milliseconds internally is a very common cause of bugs.